# Keep losing power and after some time it comes back on?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Keep losing power to 1 living room and all kitchen outlets, light above sink, clothes dryer and porch light.  The circuit breakers are not tripped, and after a random amount of time the power comes back on...and equally random times go out again. Why is this happening???

Comment: Do you happen to have a Federal Pacific load center? They used to be very common but have a large number of problems they can cause.

Answer (score 3):

I would unplug anything plugged in to the receptacles that are loosing power. Call your power company and tell them what is going on. You maybe loosing a phase of power at the panel and or the meter. You all so need to call a local electrical company and have them check the panel.